# JSON File: npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE npm ERR! Failed to parse json

Tags: json, reactjs

Having trouble getting my reactjs environment up and working.

JSON CODE

```
{
  "name": "basic-reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y"
  },

  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

After running the command `npm start`. I am getting this error message

```
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Monster\Documents\Project\Inital Test\reactjs practice\basic-reactjs\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '' at 10:5
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Monster\Documents\Project\Inital Test\reactjs practice\basic-reactjs\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Monster\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-24T18_44_01_709Z-debug.log
```

I am not familiar with JSON and need serious assistance.
Please Help.

Comment: Try wrapping the outer brackets with a single quote

Comment: @AllenMoh Wrapping with a quote would make it a String...